# What does loss layer do during inference ? To be clear during the forward propagation

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am having a model that uses a very large number of ops for l2 loss. And this ends up being more than the number of mul and add ops. I want to know if it's possible to remove them ? And if not why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inference refers to the process of using a trained deep learning algorithm to make a prediction. So during this time network perform classify, recognize and process new inputs.

Where as before the training of the network begins, the weights in the convolution and fully-connected layers are given random values.

Then during training, the loss layer continually checks the fully-connected layer's guesses against the actual values with the goal of minimizing the difference between the guess and the real value as much as possible.

The loss layer does this by adjusting the weights in the convolution and fully-connected layers by using `loss function` otherwise we may ended up with `Overfitting` or `Underfitting` problems. Without loss function it is difficult to measure performance of network/model.

*Generally, L2 Loss Function is preferred in most of the cases.*

I guess, if you are calculating `L2 loss` manually in your model, i recommend to use Tensorflow functions as below

```
def loss(target_y, predicted_y):
  return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(target_y - predicted_y))
```

Here am showing how to perform `L2 loss` in TF 1.x using `Session`

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()
session = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)

y = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype= tf.float32)
p = tf.constant([[0,1],[4,5]],dtype= tf.float32)

mse=tf.nn.l2_loss(y - p)

mse_eval= session.run(mse)
print(mse_eval)

session.close()
```

Output:

```
2.0
```